# MYSQL query to order by experience

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to order by experience in ASc order. I need to select the students of particular course and order them based on their expreience in ascending order.Please help me. Here is the code

```
Search Skills:</label>
<select name="skill" style="width: 220px; border:solid 1px #5A380D; height: 38px; margin-left:35px; border: 1px solid #0d82b9; " >
    <option   value="selectopt1" >------Select Course-----</option>
          <option value="Electricals and Electronics">Electricals and Electronics</option>
          <option value="Ites">Ites</option>
          <option value="Hotel Management">Hotel Management</option><option value="Beauty Culture">Beauty Culture</option>
          <option value="Retail Management">Retail Management</option></select>
</td></tr>


</td></tr><tr>
<td align="right"><br />
<input type="hidden" name="formType" id="formType" value="reg"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button">

$dbserver="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";
$dbname="ABC";
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle) or die('cannot select db');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$skill=$_POST["skill"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `resume` WHERE skill ='$skill' ORDER by exp1";
$run = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
echo "<script>window.open('searchmem.php?skill=".$skill."', '_self')</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script>alert('do not Exist!')</script>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What results do you get at the moment? Also, `mysql_` functions are deprecated and vulnerable to SQL injection. Try to move to `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Comment: ... what the ..? Has something gone wrong when posting that code? You can't just mash together HTML and PHP like that and expect it to do anything O_O Where are the `<?php .. ?>` tags?

Comment: obviously, this is not your full code. No way to find out why your code is failing. You're going to have to define "not working" and what steps have you done to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `resume` WHERE skill ='$skill' ORDER by exp1 asc";
```

Comment: `ASC` is implied by default when there's an `ORDER BY` ... this makes no difference.

Comment: What kind of values your exp1 column contains

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to write in capital letters of SQL keywords like as follow, it work safely without any version problem.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `resume` WHERE `skill` = '$skill' ORDER BY exp1 ASC";
```